# What happens when you call FragmentTransaction.replace() on a fragment container?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin

My app has 1 activity and multiple fragments.

The container is a `FrameLayout` in my activity, and after the initial fragment is added to that container, `replace()` is then used to change fragments.

**Initial add**: `transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, "FirstFragment")`

**After initial add**: `transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, "FragmentTag")`

**activity_main.xml**

```
...
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNav">
</FrameLayout>
...
```

My question is, what exactly happens when I add and replace a fragment to `R.id.fragment_layout`?

Say my fragments are all `ConstraintLayout` - is the `ConstraintLayout` nested inside the `FrameLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your `ConstrainLayout` will be nested in `FrameLayout`, just open the `Layout Inspector`(Tools -> Layout Inspector) and you will see the following:
[image]